# In an ExpandableListView which occupies less than screen size, How to show a selected group at top of screen

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In ExpandableListView, How to show a selected group at top with list items occupying space less than screen size.
For example, I have 3 groups and each group has 3 childs. If I select/expand 3rd group, total 6 list items are visible on screen but it doesn't occupy whole screen. Now I want to show the selected 3rd group at top of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont u just let the ListView scroll down to the expanded view?
Anyway, if you want it your way, you can change the getGroupView(position) so that it returns the selected Parent view for position 0 after you expanded it. then call adapter.nofityDataSetChanged() to reload the listview

Comment: Thanks danijoo. Good idea!!
But My application requires it in other way. Probably, I need to add dummy list items at the end of child listview and make the selected group at top of screen by calling setSelection(position). 
Thanks again!!